# Passing query as a parameter for executeQuery()

Tags: mysql, jsp

I developed a HTML form and the user should choose from the displayed options. These values are retrieved in the jsp page as follows:

```
String regd=request.getParameter("course");
String semester=request.getParameter("semester");
String Month=request.getParameter("Month"); 
String Year=request.getParameter("Year"); 
String type_1=request.getParameter("type");
String regulation=request.getParameter("regulation");
```

When any of the value is not equal to "all", then a sub string should be added to the query. This is as follows:

```
String count_query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `student_details`,`semester_regd_students` WHERE `semester_regd_students`.`regd_no`=`student_details`.`regd_no` ";
String select_query="SELECT * FROM `student_details`,`semester_regd_students` WHERE `semester_regd_students`.`regd_no`=`student_details`.`regd_no` ";
if(!regd.equals("all"))
             query=query+" and `Dept_Id`='"+regd+"'";
if(!semester.equals("all")) 
             query=query+" and `Semester`='"+semester+"'";
if(!Month.equals("all")) 
             query=query+" and `Month`='"+Month+"'";
if(!Year.equals("all")) 
             query=query+" and `Year`='"+Year+"'";
if(!type_1.equals("all")) 
             query=query+" and `type`='"+type_1+"'";
if(!regulation.equals("all")) 
             query=query+" and `Regulation`='"+regulation+"'";

count_query=count_query+query;
```

When I try to execute the above query, with the following method

```
ResultSet rs_count_query=S.executeQuery(count_query);
if(rs_count_query.getInt("COUNT(*)")<=0)
{
    out.println("We have no records for the input data!!! Please go back and verify . . .");
    out.println("Please make sure that, you have no pending verifications . . .");
}
```

I have an exception and it is

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Exam Cell/data_dept.jsp at line 33

   30:      count_query=count_query+query;
   31:      out.println(count_query);
   32:      ResultSet rs_count_query=S.executeQuery(count_query);
   33:      if(rs_count_query.getInt("COUNT(*)")<=0)
   34:      {
   35:          out.println("We have no records for the input data!!!                   Please go back and verify . . .");
   36:          out.println("Please make sure that, you have no pending              verifications . . .");.
```

What could be the problem by passing the parameter into executeQuery?

Comment: Read the stack trace of the exception. It will tell you. And please, stop having Java code in JSPs. This code should be in a Java class, called from a controller (servlet). `rs_count_query.getInt("COUNT(*)")` is probably the problem. The stack trace will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

As per error stack trace, error is on line `33`:

```
32:      ResultSet rs_count_query=S.executeQuery(count_query);
33:      if(rs_count_query.getInt("COUNT(*)")<=0)
```

When a `ResultSet` is generated its row position state would be *before start*.
It means that, it is *not ready* to read the rows. You can check if it can traverse through the rows by calling `next()`. It returns a `boolean` and indicates whether there are any rows to read and moves the row position to the *next* available row, when *true*.

In your case you did not call `next()` method and hence it throws an `SQLException` with message `Before start of result set`.

Change your code as below:
**Example**:

```
ResultSet rs_count_query=S.executeQuery(count_query);
if( rs_count_query.next() && rs_count_query.getInt( "COUNT(*)" ) <= 0 )
{
    out.println("We have no rec...... ...");
    out.println("Please make sure tha..... . . .");
}
```

Alternatively, in case if you are executing a *single row* returning statements, you cane use `absolute` to move the cursor to that specific row to read.

**Example**:

```
ResultSet rs_count_query=S.executeQuery(count_query);
rs_count_query.absolute( 1 );
if( rs_count_query.getInt( "COUNT(*)" ) <= 0 )
{
    out.println("We have no rec...... ...");
    out.println("Please make sure tha..... . . .");
}
```

**Suggestions**:
It would be a better option using column index number, while reading columns, when alias names are not defined on expressions.

Change: `getInt( "count(*)" )` to: `getInt( 1 )`

Count always returns a `0` or a position whole number. You need not check if a negative value is returned.

Change: `getInt( "count(*)" ) <= 0`,
to: `getInt( "count(*)" ) == 0`
or to: `getInt( 1 ) == 0`

***Refer to***:

1. [boolean next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29)

   - Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.
2. [boolean absolute( int row )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#absolute%28int%29)

   - Moves the cursor to the given row number in this ResultSet object.